# How can I prevent Eclipse from adding the 'final' for certain lines of Java code?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

For example, GWT 2.4.0 still complains "Field 'private final...' will not be serialized because it is final".

The easiest way is to add a setter (or any dummy-method, making the assignment of local variable, which we want to prevent becoming final (if, for instance, setter already have and it does not assign)).

Comment: Do you use some kind of code generator ? Because I don't understand the question... Personaly I prevent the "final" modificator by not writing it in the first place...

Comment: @Stephan GWT does not use java serialization but a custom java<->javascript one... not sure overriding readObject will do anything to this specific problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the settings under `Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions > Additional Actions > Configure... > Code Style`

And regarding your comment:

> I want to disable adding the modifier to a single line, not the entire
>   project.

Eclipse doesn't really have a clean way to do this. What you *could* do is just open the file with the Eclipse Text Editor instead of the Java Editor and delete the `final` keyword manually, but I'm afraid there's not much you can do beyond that.

Or create an unused method that re-assigns the field, but that's kind of hacky as well.

Comment: I want to disable adding the modifier to a single line, not the entire project.

Comment: Thank you, I've used this hack:)

Comment: as i can't answer to the right place i will comment your comment on my comment here... i wasn't saying final shouldn't be used, just that when i don't want something to be 'final' i don't add the modificator (apparently the user automated it, the part of the question i didn't understand). And i do most of the time what the answers in the discussion you pointed state (always on immutable fields, rarely on parameters i admit - unlike when i worked with c). But i know it's hard to change habits to adapt a new tech (and GWT when i learned it wasnt always friendly with old java habits)

Comment: @Vinze I have used the automated way for years, and it makes things so much easier :-)

Comment: i can't agree more... but "in theory there's no difference between theory and practice, but in practice there is"... and I'm now used to forget all my habits from a project to another (i now must do java 1.3 compatible code which was already deprecated when i learned java and i have neither delorean neither tardis...) so i never automate anything, it's too frustrating when you can't use it anymore (ok i keep autocompletion) :( maybe I should instead of overcomplicating my job :)

Comment: @Andrew that didn't exist back then. You might consider adding it as an answer now.